# Overriding IE=EmulateIE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility, meta-tags

I have a purchased theme for Wordpress that automatically sets the X-UA-Compatible to IE=EmulateIE7.  This, is not allowing some of the more complex custom scripting to function properly.

Since this purchased theme will be used across my company, we do NOT want to modify any of the core scripts, so when we do updates, nothing reverts back.

Can I simply add a X-UA Compatible to IE=edge to override the IE7 Emulation, or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: remove the meta tag from the theme that is setting it? I bet when you do that, all of the CSS will break! You might want to ask for a refund. lol

Comment: without modify any script!? hmmm it's impossible.

Comment: what I meant to say was, without directly deleting the original meta tag for the X-UA Compatibility.  I have the option to add code, I just can't modify the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA... simply writing a second meta X-UA tag and setting it to IE-edge does override any previous meta tags.

IT'S A MIRACLE!